# Lightning EarPods + Mac

Tags: mac, usb, lightning, headphones

Looking the [Lightning Earpods](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMTN2AM/A/earpods-with-lightning-connector), but can't seem to find a USB 3 or 2 to Female Lightning adapter. Anyone know anything or where I could find one?

Comment: AFAIK, you're not intended to use them with Macs. Interesting question though.

Comment: @JMY1000 is correct.  Apple sells Lightning to USB connectors but they're only for use with cameras.

Comment: @fbara Seems like an answer right there ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the system requirements on the [Lightning EarPods store page](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMTN2AM/A/earpods-with-lightning-connector), an iPhone, iPod or iPad running iOS 10 or higher is required to use them. Even if you had a USB adapter it wouldn't work because there are no drivers in the OS for them.